# Convert imageview into a base64 string

Tags: java, android, json

can i use base64 string converter in android imageview ?
if yes then how..please help..
i try out with this following code..

```
ImageView iv;
iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = iv.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
```

then i want to send img_str as a json data into my server..please help guys

Answer (score 0):

```
You can decode the string that you just encoded and get the image back by doing something like the following:

byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(strBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);

And u can send string to server this way :

 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(ur_string);
```

Comment: thanx for your answer, but I want to send this img_str string as a json data into my server which will insert into mysql database..
is it possible?

Comment: yes that fine, u can encode that string and send it..., i hv edited answer

Comment: This is my json code .. its getting no error..but its not working in server side

{ JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("name", nm);
json.put("comments", com);
json.put("img", img_str);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url = "http://share88.hostzi.com/parser/json_req.php";

 HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));

request.setHeader("json", json.toString());

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); }

Comment: No error but it is not inserting into my server mysql database..i used img field as mediumblob type

Comment: ok can u say me the code u r writing on server site is that php? and u r running server side code on remote or local server?

Comment: yes it is php code and a free domain i used...
php code is..
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

include "connect.php";


mysql_query("INSERT INTO emp VALUES ('','".$obj->{'name'}."', '".$obj->{'comments'}."', '".$obj->{'img'}."')");
mysql_close($con);


?>

Comment: when i sending text data by this process its inserting fine..but image encoded string does not

Comment: $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

include "connect.php";


mysql_query("INSERT INTO emp VALUES ('','".$obj->{'name'}."', '".$obj->{'comments'}."', '".$obj->{'img'}."')");
mysql_close($con);

Comment: plz paste in pastie.org?

Comment: change this file_get_contents("php://input");

Comment: and i thing double quote of insert statement is not completed properly plz check ur syntax once in insert query....

Comment: but if i delete this line **file_get_contents("php://input");** , then how i get the json data..?

Comment: ok got it.. but what argument i pass inside **file_get_contents("php://input");**

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two steps

**1. create byte array from ImageView (drawable)**

```
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.images);   
//R.drawable.images is image for my ImageView
ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
byte[] imageByteArray=stream.toByteArray();
System.out.println("byte array:"+ imageByteArray);
```

**2. convert byte array to base64 string**

```
String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray, 0);
System.out.println("string:"+img_str);
```

Cheers!!